# How to generate dynamically filled PDFs from templates using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to generate some PDFs which will have some dynamically filled data. I am looking for the easiest options that will allow me to define some templates using HTML or PUG and then fill these templates with my data to generate PDFs.

So far I have looked at `PDF-LIB` and `node-pdftk` but they doesn't support HTML or PUG templates. Every time I have to change the layout or add some new fields in the PDF, I will have to make changes in the JS code, whereas PUG and HTML templates are much easier to edit.

What are some libraries that can do this?

Comment: " html-pdf " with ejs

Comment: I believe you want to ask this here instead: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/